# Salt deposits in health faucets and shower

Tags: faucet, clog

Due to the quality of water (with lots of dissolved salts) the health faucet and the shower gets clogged. I have to either poke with a pin or open it and brush. This happens very frequently (at least once a month). Is there a solution to avoid the problem or an easier remedy....

Comment: Soaking in vinegar or using CLR (Calcium, Lime and Rust Remover) is much more effective at removing mineral deposits.

Answer (score 1):

A water softener is one solution. It filters out the dissolved salts.

Comment: Water softener uses an ion exchange column to replace calcium and other ions with more soluble sodium ions. It does not filter out dissolved salts, it replaces them one for another. To filter out dissolved salts you need a reverse osmosis setup. (Distillation would also work, but is hugely expensive.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Altering the quality of the incoming water is not possible as I stay at a high-rise apartment. I can, for now, only look for solutions post-facto. And also repeating the solution periodically.